# Changing Output of Count Function

Tags: sql

I am working on creating a query that will start with a base cost of $230 and then will take the number of parents that are coming with each person enrolled to a class session and multiply that number by $55 (the cost of each parent to attend the session).
It will then check the amount the person attending has paid so far and will subtract that from the total cost that was just calculated.
My problem is that I also need to include the email in each line and because of that I need to have the `GROUP BY GuestEmail` part of the query. With this `GROUP BY` line causes `COUNT(Guest.ID)` to always returns 1 even though in multiple cases it should return 2, 3, or 4.

```
SELECT Registration.ID, Guest.GuestEmail,
    CASE
        WHEN ((COUNT(Guest.ID) * 55) + 230) - SUM(DISTINCT Transaction.AuthorizationAmount) is not null
            THEN ((COUNT(Guest.ID) * 55) + 230) - SUM(DISTINCT  Transaction.AuthorizationAmount)
        WHEN ((COUNT(Guest.ID) * 55) + 230) is not null AND SUM(DISTINCT Transaction.AuthorizationAmount) is null
            THEN ((COUNT(Guest.ID) * 55) + 230)
        WHEN ((COUNT(Guest.ID) * 55) + 230) is null AND SUM(DISTINCT Transaction.AuthorizationAmount) is not null
            THEN - SUM(DISTINCT Transaction.AuthorizationAmount)
        ELSE '0'
    END AS Balance

    FROM Registration 
    LEFT JOIN Transaction ON Registration.ID = Transaction.ID 
    LEFT JOIN Guest ON Registration.ID = Guest.ID 

    WHERE Registration.IsActive = 'True' AND Registration.ID = 111111 AND ConfirmationEmail = 0 AND Guest.IsActive = 'True' AND Registration.ID = Guest.ID
    GROUP BY Registration.ID, Guest.GuestEmail
```

Registration is the table that holds the student's information while Guest holds the parent's information. Each Parent is identified as their child's parents through the ID that is contained in both Registration and Guest. The ID is the same number for both the parent and the student.
Transaction.AuthorizationAmount is the amount that the enrolled person has paid already. Guest has a separate row for each guest. The email being returned is the parent's email which is stored in the Guest table.
Question: How can I change the query to cause `COUNT(Guest.ID)` to return numbers besides 1?

Comment: If I'm the one taking the class, and I'm bringing mom and dad, what table are each of us in, and how does your db identify them as my guests?  Also, whose email address do you want returned?

Comment: @Dan Bracuk Updated my question to answer those but here it is again:Registration is the table that holds the student's information while Guest holds the parent's information. Each Parent is identified as their child's parents through the ID that is contained in both Registration and Guest. The ID is the same number for both the parent and the student. Transaction.AuthorizationAmount is the amount that the enrolled person has paid already. Guest has a separate row for each guest. The email being returned is the parent's email which is stored in the Guest table.

Comment: If the money stuff pertains to me, are you sure you want to mail it to my guests?

Comment: Yeah, my boss wants it mailed to everybody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just trying this one out blindly and not sure how this query will perform but it might give you some ideas:

```
SELECT r.ID, r.balance, g.GuestEmail
FROM Guest g
JOIN (
    SELECT Registration.ID,
    CASE
        WHEN ((COUNT(Guest.ID) * 55) + 230) - SUM(DISTINCT Transaction.AuthorizationAmount) is not null
            THEN ((COUNT(Guest.ID) * 55) + 230) - SUM(DISTINCT  Transaction.AuthorizationAmount)
        WHEN ((COUNT(Guest.ID) * 55) + 230) is not null AND SUM(DISTINCT Transaction.AuthorizationAmount) is null
            THEN ((COUNT(Guest.ID) * 55) + 230)
        WHEN ((COUNT(Guest.ID) * 55) + 230) is null AND SUM(DISTINCT Transaction.AuthorizationAmount) is not null
            THEN - SUM(DISTINCT Transaction.AuthorizationAmount)
        ELSE '0'
    END AS Balance
    FROM Registration 
    LEFT JOIN Transaction ON Registration.ID = Transaction.ID 
    LEFT JOIN Guest ON Registration.ID = Guest.ID 
    WHERE Registration.IsActive = 'True' AND Registration.ID = 111111 AND ConfirmationEmail = 0 AND Guest.IsActive = 'True' AND Registration.ID = Guest.ID
    GROUP BY Registration.ID
) r ON (g.ID = r.ID)
GROUP BY g.GuestEmail
```